# Make legend correspond to colors of scatter points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have a plot that I am generating through KMeans algorithm in scikit-learn. The clusters correspond to different colors. Here is the plot,
[image]

I need a legend for this plot which corresponds to the cluster number in the plot. Ideally, the legend should display the color of the cluster and the label should be the cluster number. Thanks.

EDIT: I think I should put some code since people are downvoting this

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=20, init='random')   
km.fit(df)  #df is the dataframe which contains points as coordinates
labels = km.labels_
plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='w', frame_on=True)
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)

# Plot the clusters on the map
# m is a basemap object
m.scatter(
         [geom.x for geom in map_points],
         [geom.y for geom in map_points],
         20, marker='o', lw=.25,
         c = labels.astype(float),
         alpha =0.9, antialiased=True,
         zorder=3)
m.fillcontinents(color='#555555')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You could plot each cluster with a separate `m.scatter()` command, or as an alternative make a discrete colorbar with the all the classes. In the sklearn gallery are examples showing how to do this. People wont be able to run your example, so that's hard to work with...

Comment: Thanks @RutgerKassies..I will check out the sklearn gallery

Comment: @Nitin, if you came up with a solution, please post it back here

Comment: @Nitin how did you put coordinates on a map image? i have a problem with that

Comment: @sanaz I don't have access to this code anymore but from what I remember the map_points list you see below had namedtuples which had a x and y coordinate that you could supply to the scatter function.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to make the legend correspond to the color. The key was using multiple scatterplots for each category in the data as mentioned by Rutger Kassies.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Setting various plot properties
plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='w', frame_on=True)
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)

# Creating a discrete colorbar
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, 20))

current_plot_range = 0
previous_plot_range = 0

for i,c in enumerate(colors):
  previous_plot_range += current_plot_range
  current_plot_range = labels[labels==i].size
  m.scatter(
       [geom.x for geom in map_points[      
             previous_plot_range:previous_plot_range+current_plot_range]],
       [geom.y for geom in map_points[
             previous_plot_range:previous_plot_range+current_plot_range]],
       20, lw=.25, marker='o',color = c, label=i, alpha =0.9, antialiased=True, 
       zorder=3)

plt.legend()
m.fillcontinents(color='#555555')
```

The result looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer! You can consider to use enumerate instead of zip.